# Cannot proceed on ubuntu upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade from 10.04 or 11.10 to 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04)

I am trying to upgrade 10.04 to 12.04
My system is Linux patmos 2.6.32-42-generic #96-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 15 19:37:37 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
However, I get the following error during the upgrade. 
Anyone could help?
Thanks!

```
Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
Calculating the changes
Calculating the changes
The software on this computer is up to date. 
There are no upgrades available for your system. The upgrade will now be canceled. 
Do you want to start the upgrade?
```